# vbLf Puts a Line Break Between Lines

Tags: excel, vba, csv

In VBA, I am trying to make the end of line a Unix, LF type, when exporting a CSV. For instance,

```
Print #1, x & vbLf
```

But this causes a double space in the lines of text, for example,

```
This is text.

This is also text.
```

It should be

```
This is text.
This is also text.
```

But when I exclude the Lf, CtLf or Cr, I have to manually convert it to Lf in Notepad++

How can I accomplish this in VBA, without having to manually open Notepad++ and convert to Unix(Lf)?

Comment: Try adding trailing semi colon `Print #1, x & vbLf;`

Comment: Thank you! That's what it was. Can you explain why it needed a ";"? Post that as an answer, so I can give you credit.

Comment: Its ok, credit belongs to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444887/avoid-extra-carriage-return-in-print-statement-with-visual-basic