# Generate TXT without last white line

Tags: excel, vba

I need to generate txt without the last line in white.
The next code usually use, but the result is  with the last white line:

```
'path to the text file (MAKE SURE TO CHANGE IT)
'myFile = "C:\Users\amorante\Downloads\ValidacionesSunatEdufarma\" & j & ".txt"
myFile = varRuta & j & ".txt"

'define FreeFile to the variable file number
TextFile = FreeFile

'using append command to add text to the end of the file
Open myFile For Output As TextFile

'loop to add data to the text file
For i = 1 To batchSaldoUnidades
Print #TextFile, Sheets("PEAJES - EDUFARMA").Range("K" & k)

'Print #TextFile, Cells(i, 2)

k = k + 1

Next i

'close command to close the text file after adding data
Close #TextFile
```

Comment: _using append command_ ? `Open myFile For Output As TextFile` is not appending How many lines in output , less than 10,000 ?

Comment: When `i` = `batchSaldoUnidades`, use `Print #TextFile, Sheets("PEAJES - EDUFARMA").Range("K" & k);`  (note trailing semicolon) to suppress the newline on the last output.

Comment: ...see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444887/avoid-extra-carriage-return-in-print-statement-with-visual-basic

Comment: @braX 
I use batchSaldoUnidades to capture the last batch of cells that I have  to print in txt file. Because need batch of 100 units. Its a varable.

Comment: @CDP1802 
Thanks for the answer.
The lines in output are batch of 100 maximum.